# Extend object to be used in pipe

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to extend the VMware PowerCli cmdlet `Get-VM` to have my values in its fields and to pass it through the pipe.

For example, I would like to see `MyField1` and `MyField2` in the object. This can be achieved by ps1xml file.

```
PS C:\> get-vm -name linux1 | fl *


MyField1                : #value1#
MyField2                : #value2#
PowerState              : PoweredOff
Version                 : v8
Description             :
Notes                   :
Guest                   : suse11sp3-3:SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 (64-bit)
...
...
```

When I try to use the fields from the pipe I get nothing.

```
PS C:\> get-vm -name linux1 | other-cmdlet {$_.MyField1}
```

For example, here I will use `Select-Object` cmdlet but these is nothing:

```
PS C:\> get-vm -name linux1 | other-cmdlet {$_.MyField1}
    $_.MyField
    ----------
```

How can I truly extends an object, in my case `VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Inventory.VirtualMachineImpl` to have some extended capabilities and to pass these values to pipe?

Comment: I forgot to add that MyField1 and MyField2 are not static but holds values from a pscmdlet I've written

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Add-Member` cmdlet. For example:

```
$VM = get-vm -name linux1
$VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyField1 -Value "#value#"

$VM | Select * | fl
```

Update: then using the value for the other cmdlet:

```
other-cmdlet $($VM | Select -ExpandProperty MyField1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) are probably the most common way of adding custom properties to objects in PowerShell:

```
Get-Vm -Name linux1 |
  Select-Object *, @{n='MyField1';e={Some-Cmdlet ...}},
                @{n='MyField2';e={Other-Cmdlet ...}}
```

Another option is to use [`Add-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849879.aspx) as [@ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754280/1630171) suggested:

```
Get-Vm -Name linux1 | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyField1 -Value (Some-Cmdlet ...)
  $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MyField2 -Value (Other-Cmdlet ...)
  $_   # this line is required to actually output the modified object!
}
```